# How can I overlay text onto an image in this example?

Tags: css

I am trying to overlay "Text overlay goes here" on top of the profilepic.jpg below.  I think I am doing something wrong with the CSS.  What I tried to do was just create a new div class called overlay and I thought if I just nestled that line in between the imgcontainer class, it would work.  Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

## HTML

```
<div id="timeline">
        <div class="block2x3 block">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="profilepic.jpg" />
                <p><div class="overlay">Text Overlay Goes Here</div></p>
            </div>

            <div class="commentcontainer">
                <div class="peoples">
                    <a href="#"><strong class="peoplename">Joe Schmo</strong></a> and <a href="#">42 other people bought this</a>
                    <p>Have commented on your <a href="#">wall post</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## CSS

```css
#timeline div[class*="block2x3"] .imgcontainer  {height:66.6%;}
#timeline div[class*="block2x3"] .commentcontainer  {height: 33.4%;;}
#overlay{
    float: top;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float: top;` does not exist :) you are looking for `position: absolute`

- Set `position: absolute` on the overlay container to position over the top of the image.
- Set `position: relative` on your image container to make the overlay position itself in relation to it.
- Remove the height properties and let the content determine the height.
- Set `display: inline-block` on the image container so it will resize automatically with the images width
- Give the overlay container `width: 100%` to keep it the full width of the image.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#timeline {
    padding: 10px;  
}

.image {
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; /* allow width to be determined by the images size */    
}

.block .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; /* Full width of .image */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    color: #FFF;
}

.comment {
    padding: 10px 0 0;  
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="block2x3 block">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
            <div class="overlay">Text Overlay Goes Here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            <a href="#"><strong class="peoplename">Joe Schmo</strong></a> and <a href="#">42 other people bought this</a>
            <p>Has commented on your <a href="#">wall post</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated - I have made a few changes so that the width of the image container and overlay is now determined by the size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to make that work: http://jsfiddle.net/codershop/ddg2ymxm/

Remove the paragraph tags from around the overlay div.

```
<div class="overlay">Text Overlay Goes Here</div>
```

In the css change the #overlay selector to a class selector .overlay.  Like this:

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I did this but for some reason it's still not showing up.  Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Can you update the jsfiddle I created to be more like your example?